# MySQL - Saving and loading

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working on a game, and just a while ago i started getting start on loading and saving.

I've been thinking, but i really can't decide, since I'm not sure which would be more efficient.

My first option: 
When a user registers, only the one record is inserted (into 'characters' table). When the user tries to login, and after he/she has done so successfully, the server will try loading all information from the user (which is separate across multiple tables, and combines via mysql 'LEFT JOIN'), it'll run though all the information it has and apply them to the entity instance, if it runs into a NULL (which means the information isn't in the database yet) it'll automatically use a default value. 
At saving, it'll insert or update, so that any defaults that have been generated at loading will be saved now.

My second option:
Simply insert all the required rows at registration (rows are inserted when from website when the registration is finished).

Downsides to first option: useless checks if the user has logged in once already, since all the tables will be generated after first login.

Upsides to first option: if any records from tables are deleted, it would insert default data instead of kicking player off saying it's character information is damaged/lost.

Downsides to second option: it could waste a bit of memory, since all tables are inserted at registration, and there could be spamming bots, and people who don't even manage to get online.

Upsides to first option: We don't have to check for anything in the server.

I also noted that the first option may screw up any search systems (via admincp, if we try looking a specific users).

Comment: Would you provide some detail about what kind of information you're talking about? What sorts of data is coming from these other tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go with the second option, add default rows to your user account, and flag the main user table as incomplete.  This will maintain data integrity across your database, whereas every user record is complete in it's entirety.  If you need to remove the record, you can simply add a cascading delete script to clean house.

Also, I wouldn't develop your data schema based off of malacious bots creating accounts.  If you are concerned about the integrity of your user accounts, add some sort of data validation into your solution or an automated clean-house script to clear out incomplete accounts once the meet a certain criteria, i.e. the date created meeting a certain threshold.

Comment: The other advantage is that you do not need to worry about missing records in the rest of your code.  With the first aproach you risk having special cases everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that there's multiple tables of data for each user, with some that can have a default value if none exist in the table. I'm guessing this is set up something like a main "characters" table, with username, password, and email, and a separate table for something like "favorite shortcuts around the site", and if they haven't specified personal preferences, it defaults to a basic list of "profile, games list, games by category" etc.

Then the question becomes when registering, should an explicit copy of the favorite shortcuts default be added for that user, or have the null value default to a default list?

I'd suggest that it depends on the nature of the auxiliary data tables; specifically the default value for those tables. How often would the defaults change? If the default changes often, a setup like your first option would result in users with only a 'basic' entry would frequently get new auxiliary data, while those that did specify their own entries would keep their preferences. Using your second option, if the default changed, in order to keep users updated, a search/replace would have to be done to change entries that were the old default to the new default.

The other suggestion is to take another look at your database structure. You don't mention that your current table layout is set in stone; is there a way to not have all the LEFT JOIN tables, and have just one 'characters' table?